# How to get data from stored procedure using EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to call a stored procedure and assign the result to a list.

I know I have it wrong but this is what I have so far:

```
var result = this.Database
            .SqlQuery<PersonModel>("spMySP_Select").ToList???;
```

There does not seem to be a `.ToList` only `.ToListAsAsync`

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: what does you sp return?

Comment: If `ToList` doesn't show up in intellisense you may need to add `using System.Linq` to the top of the code file.

Comment: What **version** of EF are you using?? Are you using the pre-release EF **7** by any chance??